# Working with Android Framework

Tags: android, frameworks

I wanted to modify/customize the android framework. I am a complete newbie in framework related stuffs. So how do i start with it?

Please suggest me some good place to start with it and initial steps and what are the future trends related to framework?

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: please elaborate your question more specificly, its a very broad question.

Comment: I think he is trying to ask how to provide a custom android sdk. E.g. "android-4.0-sneha-added"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the android source code.

http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

2. Make your changes to the android framework code

   - Modify existing classes
   - Add new classes.
     etc
3. In the downloaded source directory, please find: 
   `/devlopement/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt`. It should be something like [this](https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/qrd-gb-dsds-7225/repository/revisions/cc99b832a941dc8cbb86f1607d04eb87935ddbfd/entry/android/development/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt).
4. Follow the steps to build your own sdk. To build an SDK for MacOS and Linux, these are the steps:

   ```
   $ cd ~/my-android-git
   $ . build/envsetup.sh
   $ lunch sdk-eng
   $ make sdk
   ```

Comment: thank you.. nice to know more about it and future possible enhancements too!:-)